# Optimize recursive script to bulk add SVG elements to DOM

Tags: javascript, web, recursion, svg, dom

I’m looking to dynamically bulk add a lot of SVG elements to the DOM.

From what I’ve read, dynamically adding SVG elements requires less processing than creating multiple instances with the SVG ‘use’ statement.

I wrote the script below.  Am I missing any more optimal approaches?

Or can this structure be accomplished with fewer iterations?

I’ll have to be able to target the immediate parent for each element in order to add it to the DOM structure.

The script below is designed to create a one-to-many relationship between each element and every element on the level below it for any number of layers defined by the array.

```
`console.clear();

newElement = [];

newElement[0] = ["g", "g"];
newElement[1] = ["g", "g", "g"];
newElement[2] = ["g", "g", "g"];
newElement[3] = ["path", "polygon", "path", "polygon"];

coord = [];
Tree(-1, 0);
console.table(coord);

function Tree(f, i) {
  (origf = f),
    (origi = i),
    (tracki = []),
    (trackf = origf + 1),
    (tracki[trackf] = 0);

  coord.push([trackf, tracki[trackf]]);

  while (AddDesc() != "done") {
    AddDesc();
  }
}

function AddDesc() {
  if (trackf == newElement.length - 1) {
    for (
      tracki[trackf] = 1;
      tracki[trackf] < newElement[trackf].length;
      tracki[trackf]++
    ) {
      coord.push([trackf, tracki[trackf]]);
    }
    trackf--;

    for (
      ;
      trackf > origf && tracki[trackf] == newElement[trackf].length - 1;
      trackf--
    ) {}
    if (trackf == origf) {
      return "done";
    }
    tracki[trackf]++;
    coord.push([trackf, tracki[trackf]]);
  }

  if (trackf < newElement.length - 1) {
    trackf = trackf + 1;
    tracki[trackf] = 0;
    coord.push([trackf, tracki[trackf]]);
  }
}`
```

This was my first attempt.

Comment: It is really difficult to read your code. Maybe you could add the end result -- the resulting SVG element based on your code.

Comment: Thanks.  Here is the codepen.  This code only generates the coordinates in the newElement array for the SVG type for each element.  Classes and attributes for each element are in other arrays with identical coordinates for each element.  I haven't put them all together yet because I got stuck on the best technique to place each element in the DOM SVG tree.  I've included a codepen for the SVG this section of code is building.  https://codepen.io/fcdobbs/pen/oNMoeGa   https://codepen.io/fcdobbs/pen/zYLpRdJ